# Sprite under map

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hello i have some sprite and some map

-(id) init
{

```
if( (self=[super init] )) {

    self.tiledMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"map3.tmx"];
    self.background = [_map layerNamed:@"Background"];
    [self.tiledMap runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:10.0 position:ccp(0,-2750)]];


    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"AnimBear.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"AnimBear.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];
    NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8 ; ++i) {
        [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bear%d.png", i]]];
    }
    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    self.bug = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bear1.png"];
    _bug.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    self.walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];




    [_bug runAction:_walkAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:_bug];
    [self addChild:_map];
}
return self;
```

}

and my sprite is under map , but i need to draw sprite on map. How can i do it?
tnaks

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that ure missing the z value, that tells the order of the stuff,

```
[spriteSheet addChild:_bug z:2];
[self addChild:_map z:1];
```

The layer organizes the objects that are infront of or behind using zOrder the lowest the value, the far is the thing from the screen.